# Select Distinct in inner join with full customer record

Tags: sql, datetime, count, inner-join, distinct

I have two tables one with customer and another with invoices. I need to find all customer that have an more that one invoice with different days with in a period.

Invoice table:
Accountnum
Datein
IStatus
...

Customer table:
Accountnum
...

I have two problems:

1:
I can get the customers that have more than one invoice, but I don't know how to check if they are different days.

2:
Customer shows more than one time in this query they need to show only ones.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Invoice I
INNER JOIN Customer C
ON I.Accountnum= C.Accountnum
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT I.AccountnumFROM Invoice
         WHERE C.Accountnum = I.Accountnum
         and i.Datein >= '2020-03-01' and i.Datein <= '2020-05-31'
         and (IStatus <> 'V' or IStatus IS NULL)
         GROUP BY I.Accountnum
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to check if a given customer has invoices on two different dates is to ensure that the minimum invoice date differs from the maximum invoice date. You could write this as a `join` query:

```
select c.*
from customer c
inner join (
    select accountnum
    from invoice
    where 
        datein >= '2020-03-01' and datein <= '2020-05-31' 
        and (istatus <> 'V' or istatus is null)
    group by accountnum
    having min(datein) <> max(datein)
) i on i.accountnum = c.accountnum
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but no `JOIN` in the outer query:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer C
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Invoice
       WHERE C.Accountnum = I.Accountnum AND
            i.Datein >= '2020-03-01' and i.Datein <= '2020-05-31' AND
            (IStatus <> 'V' or IStatus IS NULL)
      ) > 1;
```

Note that I also changed the logic of the subquery.  The subquery returns a count which is then compared to `1`, rather than using `EXISTS`.

Comment: This worked, but I get customer that have two or more invoice, but all on the same date. Thanks